# Why are my props not being bound dynamically?

Tags: vue.js

I have the following component that I have built which is a checkbox of types:

```
<mapFilterCheckbox v-bind:selected="allSelected" v-bind:label="getCleanedTitle(category.name)" v-bind:count="category.count" v-on:click.native="filterPostsByCategory(category.slug)"/>
```

I have specified the `prop` of `selected` which is dynamically bound to the variable `this.allSelected`. I also have another button elsewhere in my pattern which sets the variable `this.allSelected` to false when clicked.

However, this change is not being passed down to the child component as a prop - and I am absolutely unsure as to why. This is the `mapFilterCheckbox` component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="vue-taxonomy-select clearfix" v-bind:class="{ 'vue-taxonomy-select__active': checked }" v-on:click="checkBoxClick()">

      <div class="float-left">
        <font-awesome-icon :icon="icon" class="mr-3"/>
        <span class="text-dark" v-html="label"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="float-right">
        <small class="font-weight-bold text-teal">{{ count }}</small>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'mapFilterCheckbox',
  props: {
    label: String,
    count: [String, Number],
    selected: Boolean,
  },
  data () {
    return {
      checked: this.selected,
      icon: this.selected ? ['fal', 'check-square'] : ['fal', 'square']
    }
  },
  watch: {
    selected () {
      console.log(this.selected)
    },
    checked () {
      if (this.checked) {
        this.icon = ['fal', 'check-square']
      }

      if (!this.checked) {
        this.icon = ['fal', 'square']
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkBoxClick () {
      this.checked = !this.checked
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The watcher for selected doesn't register a change of the selected value...the change of the value allSelected doesn't also change either this.checked or the icon...so for me, the `prop` `selected` isn't being mutated by the parent component?

It only works when I originally set `allSelected` in the data object of the parent component to either true or false, everything works as expected.

So, how on Earth do I get this mutation to register with the child component??

****UPDATE**** Ok - so the value of `allSelected` once set when clicking on `resetAllFilters`, is false - so it never updates after the initial click...*how do I propagate the change even if it I'm setting it back to `false` from it being `false`*??

Comment: I would think using a computed property would be the way to go...

Comment: @iceman - I have tried this and it doesn't; seem to work - I have tried computing `this.checked` in the mapFilterCheckbox child on the value of the prop `this.selected` being passed in, but then I'm setting it inside the checkBoxClick method, so unfortunately I can't then use that method...the setter errors comes back with a maximum call stack issue.

Comment: @iceman if you could outline an example that would work - and believe me I have tried everything I can possibly think of with a computed get set method, then I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: @Iceman It looks to me that when I initially trigger the resetAllFilters click event method - allSelected gets set from true, to false. Any subsequent click and it's always false so not registered a change. Can I not explicitly tell Vue to change a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Change your watcher to a computed prop like this:

```
computed: {
  icon() {
    return this.checked ? ['fal', 'check-square'] : ['fal', 'square']
  }
}
```

So, *icon* variable is now reactive to any update in *checked*.